# How to i fix the "Cannot find 'present' and 'dismiss' in scope" error in swift

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to allow a user to pick an image and set it as there banner on there profile page but when i write my code i keep getting the error "Cannot find 'present' in scope" when trying to present the imagePicker and i also get "Cannot find 'dismiss' in scope" when trying to dismiss the imagePicker

here is my code for the above:

```
//this function gets called when the user tapes on the banner to change the image

class ProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@objc func handleBannerTapped() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let bannerPicture = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        imageSelected = true
        return
    }
    imageSelected = true
    profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    profileBanner.setImage(bannerPicture.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

I have used the same function in my sign up page where the user chooses a profile picture and it is working fine so i am confused as to why it doesn't work now for the banner

Comment: Where is that code? In a `UIViewController` I hope. Only `UIViewController` can call `present(_:animated:completion:)`

Comment: You need to edit your question to show what class that code comes from. include the class declaration: e.g. `class myVCClass: UIViewController { <functions> }`

Answer (score 3):

You can only `present` and `dismiss` on a view controller. But ProfileHeader is not a view controller. It's a cell.

So where's the view controller? It's up the responder chain from the cell. So walk up the responder chain until you come to the view controller, and `present` and `dismiss` on that.

Here's a utility method that will help you:

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<T:UIResponder>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        let r = self.next
        if let r = r as? T ?? r?.next(ofType: T.self) {
            return r
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can say:

```
if let vc = self.next(ofType: UIViewController.self) {
    vc.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And so on.

---

However, although that will cause your code to compile, and perhaps even appear to work correctly, I think your approach here is completely wrong-headed:

- You should not be doing this work in the cell in the first place.
- You should not be having a cell telling a view controller what to present / dismiss.
- You should not be wantonly modifying the content of the cell.
- A cell is a transient reusable object, so you cannot even really guarantee that the cell will still be there (or will still occupy the same row of the table) when the image has been chosen.

Instead, the cell should just tell the view controller, hey, the user wants to pick a photo, and stand back and let the view controller do the work. The work should consist of modifying the *data model* (and then reloading the cell).